# angularjs xeditable - ng-options

Tags: angularjs, x-editable

i have problem with getting id from selected distributor. Here is my html code for select distributor

```
<span editable-select="currentKlupa.distributor" e-form="tableform" e-ng-options="user as user for user in getAllUserFromRolesPushano">{{::currentKlupa.distributor.username}}
                            </span>
```

I also have another select box, and all working correct, but this one not, because i need get id from this select.

here is controller

```
$scope.getUserFromRoles = function (rolaProslijedena) {
        $scope.getAllUserFromRolesPushano = [];
        $scope.getAllUserFromRoles = dohvacanjeUseraPoRolama.get({rola: rolaProslijedena});
        $scope.getAllUserFromRoles.$promise.then(function (data) {
            angular.forEach(data.users, function (key, value){
                $scope.getAllUserFromRolesPushano.push(key.username);
            });

        });
    };
```

I need to get id from this selected distributor, how to set ng-options for this? Thnx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without more informations, I give you an example with a tricks (i haven't found a better solution yet):

I have a **Show** done by an artist.

```
$scope.shows = {artist_id : 4};
```

and a **list of artists**.

```
$scope.artists = [{id : 1, name : 'artist1'},{id : 2, name : 'artist2'},...];
```

my html will be:

```
<span editable-select="shows.artist_id" e-name="name" e-form="rowform"  e-ng-options="g._id as g.name for g in artists">
    {{DisplayName(shows)}}
</span>
```

The **trick** is the use of DisplayName.

```
$scope.DisplayName= function(item) {
  var selected = $scope.artists.filter(function( obj ) {return (obj._id == item.artist_id)})[0]
  return selected.name;
};
```

This is really not the best solution but that works.